# What is the difference between owner and parent component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React 0.13 brings [parent-based context instead of owner-based context](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2112).

So, i can't quite understand the difference between owner and parent components. Examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var A = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <B>
                <C />
            </B>
        );
    }
});
```

In the above example, A is the **owner** of B and C, because A creates both of the components.

However, B is the **parent** of C because C is passed as child to B.

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html).

> It's important to draw a distinction between the owner-ownee
>   relationship and the parent-child relationship. The owner-ownee
>   relationship is specific to React, while the parent-child relationship
>   is simply the one you know and love from the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

From the official documentation:

`An owner is the component that sets the props of other components`

Here an example where A is the owner of B:

```
var A = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <B />;
  }
});
```

A is the owner of B because B is created in A's `render` function.

This is an example where A is the parent of B:

```
var A = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
});

var B = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <span>B</span>;
  }
});

React.render(
  <A><B /></A>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

In this example, A is the parent of B because A's `props.children` contains B. But A has no direct knowledge of that its the parent of B, its children could be any component.