# React: How to access refs in this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call a function of a child component.
Is there a possibility to get refs from this.props.children in React.

```
var ComponentSection = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {
      // How to access refs in this.props.children ?
      this.refs.inner.refs.specificPanel.resize();
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
          <div className="component-section" ref="inner">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        );
    }
});

var Panel = React.createClass({

    resize: function() {
        console.log('Panel resizing');
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
          <div className="Panel">
            Lorem   ipsum dolor sit amet 
          </div>
        );
    }
});

var MainComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
           <ComponentSection>
            <Panel ref="specificPanel"></Panel>
           </ComponentSection>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainComponent></MainComponent>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I made a little demo: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/26929/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ref in React is a relationship between a component and its *[owner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29672249/2940792)* while what you want is a relationship between an element and its *parent*. A parent-child relationship is opaque, the parent only receives the child *elements* on render and never gets access to the resolved *components*.

In your case, the `ref="specificPanel"` establishes a link from the `MainComponent` to the `Panel`. If you want to call methods of `Panel` from `ComponentSection`, it should own the `Panel`s instead of receiving them as children.

You could always get creative with `React.Children.map` and `React.createElement` (cloning the elements by hand and thus stealing them from the original owner), but this introduces some serious potential pitfalls. A better approach would likely be re-thinking the ownership structure of your component tree.

Comment: Any examples of possible pitfalls?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk I'm not sure what I meant 4 years ago. But even these days, if you try to `cloneElement` on `children` and assign new `ref`s, you'll remove the original owner's `ref`s (https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-fog-35yzf).

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to set a `ref` on a `<div>` instead of a React component.

You could also refactor your code so that only `<ComponentSection>` needs to know about the `<Panel>` component, and render it in it's render function.

```
var ComponentSection = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.refs.inner.resize();
  },

  render: function() {
    return ( 
        <div className="component-section">
            <Panel ref="inner"/>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

var MainComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( 
        <ComponentSection /> 
    );
  }
});
```

Here is a [working JSFiddlle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ksqafLh/).