# React Redux and inheritance

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm really wondering why there is nothing about Redux and how to deal with inheritance. If I have a base component:

```
class BaseComponent extends Component{

}
```

then all other components are extending `BaseComponent`:

```
class Todo extends BaseComponent {

}
```

I want to simply connect the `BaseComponent` to it's own reducer so every other component which extends it, also can access the same props and states.

Unfortunately can't find any documentation out there. I have no idea if this is a right concept or not.

Comment: That is because Inheritance is not encouraged much and the whole point of react-redux using connect this way is because it encourages HOCs. Also with inheritance, like you suggest you can only make use of props that the base component defines in mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With react you usually will not further inherit from your own components.

Here is a quote from the official docs on [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance):

> At Facebook, we use React in thousands of components, and we haven’t found any use cases where we would recommend creating component inheritance hierarchies.
>
> Props and composition give you all the flexibility you need to customize a component’s look and behavior in an explicit and safe way. Remember that components may accept arbitrary props, including primitive values, React elements, or functions.
>
> If you want to reuse non-UI functionality between components, we suggest extracting it into a separate JavaScript module. The components may import it and use that function, object, or a class, without extending it.

That being said, if you still want to deviate from the recommended way and have a base component for shared functionality, it is possible. You are still on the "safe side" (i.e. it will most likely not cause too much confusion or trouble) if you (1) reduce the functionality in your base to the least common denominator needed by most of its children (2) do not keep any shared state in your base component (3) do [not use arrow functions](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1) in your base component and if you (4) make sure to keep your lifecycle methods and `connect` in your child components to avoid unexpected behaviours.

Performing a `connect` in your base class, as you are planning to do it, would be problematic as `connect` returns a newly wrapped component which acts as an [owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671707/what-is-the-difference-between-owner-and-parent-component-in-react-js) of your actual BaseComponent (see [how connect works](https://gist.github.com/gaearon/1d19088790e70ac32ea636c025ba424e)). Therefore, you will lose the ability to access your class methods, in your ChildComponents. Also, most likely other bad things will happen because you now independently inject and manage state and lifecycles on two levels (child and base). – Therefore, your best shot, when using a custom BaseComponent, would be to not put `connect` in your parent but let the child handle the connect.

[Here is also a blog article by Dan Abramov](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/how-to-use-classes-and-sleep-at-night-9af8de78ccb4) worth reading that discusses the question of inheritance in react. His main concerns are that multi-level hierarchies are harder to refactor, name clashes will arise if a parent class later adds methods with names that some child class already uses, sharing logic between child and parent methods makes it harder to understand the code. Overall he suggests to rely on functional programming style.

> So what are my recommendations for React components?
>
> - You can use class in your JS if you don’t inherit twice and don’t use super.
> - Prefer to write React components as pure functions when possible.
>   Use ES6 classes for components if you need the state or lifecycle hooks.
> - In this case, you may only extend React.Component directly.
>   Give your feedback to the React team on the functional state proposals.

Generally speaking, whether or not hierarchies are good in OOP programming is a highly debated field.

Answer (score 2):

Inheritance is not widely preferred and encouraged in React and hence you don't find much documentation about this online. A better way to achieve what you want is to export a container which you can then wrap as a HOC to any component you wish to use it for

connectContainer.js

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
   return {}; // return data you want from reducers
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {}; // define action creators you want to pass here

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
```

Now in any component you wish to use the same container properties, you can use them like

```
import connectHOC from './connectContainer';
class Todo extends React.Component {

}
export connectHOC(Todo);
```